# OpenGL Z-Fighting issue

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am implementing an android app with OpenGL and C++, I am rendering some triangles with different Y position, all of them are in the X-Z plane, the camera is Orthographic projection with near value 3 for example.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

The orthographic projection is:

```
projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(-(width/2.f)/zoom, (width/2.f)/zoom, -(height/2.f)/zoom,(height/2.f)/zoom,near,far);
```

these values are

```
projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(-100, 100, -197,197,3,50);
```

sometimes I get the triangles seem to have Z-Fighting although they have different Y values, the camera looks at them from above.

```
            vertexShader = "#version 300 es\n"
                "precision highp float;\n"

                "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
                "layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;\n"
                "layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;\n"
                "\n"
                "uniform mat4 model;\n"
                "uniform mat4 view;\n"
                "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
                "\n"
                "out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
                "out vec3 Normal;\n"
                "out vec3 FragPos;\n"
                "\n"

                "void main(){\n"
                "   Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;\n"
                "   TexCoords = texCoord;\n"
                "   FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));\n"
                "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
                "}";

fragmentShader = "#version 300 es\n"
                "precision highp float;\n"
                "\n"
                "struct DirectLight{\n"
                "   vec3 Direction;"
                "   vec3 color;\n"
                "   float intensity;\n"
                "};\n"
                "out vec4 glFragColor;\n"
                "\n"
                "in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
                "in vec3 Normal;\n"
                "in vec3 FragPos;\n"
                "\n"
                "uniform int hasTexture;\n"
                "uniform int hasSpecular;\n"
                "uniform float alpha;\n"
                "uniform vec3 ViewPos;\n"
                "\n"
                "uniform sampler2D map_diffuse;\n"
                "uniform sampler2D map_specular;\n"
                "\n"
                "uniform vec3 diffuse;\n"
                "uniform vec3 specular;\n"
                "uniform float shininess;\n"
                "uniform DirectLight Sun1;\n"

                "vec3 calcLight(DirectLight light,vec3 diffColor,vec3 specColor){"
                "   vec3 normal      = normalize(Normal);\n"
                "   vec3 lightDir     = normalize(-light.Direction);\n"
                "   float diffFactor  = max(dot(normal,lightDir), 0.0);\n"
                "   vec3 _diffuse     = light.intensity * light.color * diffFactor * diffColor;\n"
                "   vec3 viewDir      = normalize(ViewPos - FragPos);\n"
                "   vec3 halfwayDir   = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);\n"
                "   float specFactor  = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), shininess);\n"
                "   vec3 _specular    = specColor * light.intensity * light.color * specFactor;\n"
                "   return _diffuse + _specular ;\n"
                "}"

                "void main(){\n"
                "   vec4 diffColor;\n"
                "   vec4 specColor;\n"
                "   if(hasTexture == 1)\n"
                "       diffColor = texture(map_diffuse, TexCoords);\n"
                "   else\n"
                "       diffColor = vec4(diffuse,alpha);\n"
                "   if(hasSpecular == 1)\n"
                "       specColor = texture(map_specular, TexCoords);\n"
                "   else\n"
                "       specColor = vec4(specular,alpha);\n"
                "   vec4 _ambient    = vec4(0.4,0.4,0.4,alpha) * diffColor;\n"
                "   vec4 result = vec4("
                "        calcLight(Sun1,diffColor.xyz,specColor.xyz),alpha)"
                "       + _ambient;"
                "   float gamma = 2.2;\n"
                "   result = pow(result, vec4(1.0/gamma));\n"
                "   glFragColor = result;\n"
                "}";
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share exact ortho projection parameters? The Z-fighting can also occur if values are too close. If you know exact order of your geometry, you can set polygon offset to avoid z fighting

Comment: @MrD I added the orthographic projection matrix parameters

Comment: Z range looks pretty dense, what are coords of the shown triangles?

Comment: The triangles are inside the projection box for example 80 width and 60 height and 5 in Y , there is 5 between each triangle Y.

Comment: Pls, share vertex and fragment shaders

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I added the shaders code

Comment: @MohamedMoussa Hm... Everything looks fine... Probably you should try this on another device. Also, it makes sense to try to debug it with platform tools (Adreno GPU Profiler for Qualcomm etc)